# Context Free Grammar Design

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-free-language, automata-theory

I'm learning about Context Free Grammars, and I've been understanding them so far, but this problem is kind of making my head spin.

[image: Description of language]

I have the following rules:

```
S --> aSb | bB | epsilon
B --> bbB | bB | epsilon
```

And I'm almost certain that they are incorrect. I understand how I would do just i <= j instead of the actual language, but the idea of doing j <= 3i is really hard to grasp for me and I don't really understand how I should represent that in a CFG.

I've read some questions and threads on here about designing CFG, but they didn't really help me with a strategy to determine the answer.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any `a` in a string you have to have 1, 2, or 3 `b`s in the string.

The `b`s have to follow the `a`s.

You can have zero `a`s.

```
S = A S B | e
A = a
B = b | bb | bbb
```

Zero `a`s implies no `b`s.

One `a` allows for 1, 2, or 3 `b`s.

Through recursion through `S` you can have any number of `a`s.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is indeed incorrect, because the condition j <= 3i is not obeyed.

A solution that is closer to your intent than the one from Björn, and that uses less non-terminals:

```
S -> aSb | aSbb | aSbbb | epsilon
```